# Can not test this dataClass in kotlin with mock or without

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

It pass successfully except cardNumber and termsAndCondition. These two return `null`. How can return truth values during test? (I did not remove some comments to show codes that I already tried.)

NewCardValidation.kt

```
data class NewCreditCardValidation(
    var cardNumber: MasterPassEditText? = null,
    var termsAndCondition: CompoundButton? = null,
    var cardMonth: Int? = null,
    var cardYear: Int? = null,
    var cardName: String? = null
) {
    val isValid: Boolean
        get() = when {
            cardNumber?.isEmpty == true -> false
            termsAndCondition?.isChecked == false -> false
            cardMonth == null -> false
            cardYear == null -> false
            cardName.isNullOrBlank() -> false
            else -> true
        }
}
```

NewCardValidationTest.kt

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class NewCreditCardValidationTest{
    private val newCardValidation = NewCreditCardValidation()
    @Test
    fun `Check cardValidation is valid`(){
        newCardValidation.cardNumber?.setText("4111111111111111")
      //  Mockito.`when`(newCardValidation.termsAndCondition?.isChecked).thenReturn(true)
        newCardValidation.termsAndCondition?.isChecked = true
       // doReturn(true).`when`(newCardValidation.termsAndCondition?.isChecked)
        newCardValidation.cardMonth = 10
        newCardValidation.cardYear = 2023
        newCardValidation.cardName = "mycard"
        Truth.assertThat(newCardValidation.isValid).isTrue()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `isValid` is a `val` so is created when the class is instantiated. Change it for a function and it will be computed every time, including the changes to the vars.

Comment: No, this is not problem. I can pass all other vaues and return result. But, these two pass `null`. Can't pass true or false. Also, I don't want change antyhin while doing test. That's not best practice.

Comment: Did you try it?